# React native Image Picker not working as expected

Tags: android, react-native

I get this error whenever I try to use the react-native-image picker package to select an image from the gallery. Below is the error;

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=13003, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/... flg=0x41 clip={image/* video/* {U(content)}} }}java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise.reject(java.lang.Throwable)' on a null object reference
```

My react-native codes;

```
import {launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const openGallery = () => {
    launchImageLibrary({mediaType: "photo"}).then(response => {
        if (response.assets) {
            console.log(response)
            try {
                const image = response.assets[0];
                AsyncStorage.setItem('userProfilePhoto', `${image.uri}`.toString()).then(r => {
                    console.log('Image saved to async storage.');
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: it is look like integration issue. Hope u follow documetation to integrat in android studio.